# Vulnerability Scanning Reported by AquaSec for python urlib3

Tags: python, docker, security

My python docker image is using urllib3 as 1.25.9 in the requests.txt. However, Aquasec reports a Vulnerability issue that urllib3 before version 1.23 is used. How should I solve this problem? Do I need apply some patches? Thanks!

```
urllib3 before version 1.23 does not remove the Authorization HTTP header when following a cross-origin redirect (i.e., a redirect that differs in host, port, or scheme). This can allow for credentials in the Authorization header to be exposed to unintended hosts or transmitted in cleartext.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May it be that you have a false positive? It's quite a common occurrence with all the static analysis tools meant for security analysis. The noise they generate is big. Usually 90% of issues they report are false positives.